# Magento Error 101 after installing SUPEE-6788 patch

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.7, urlrewriter

A year ago I've install **Magento 1.7.0.2**. After installing the **SUPEE-6788** patch I have several problems:
After click on any link on any page I have a blank page, and when I open the console from the browser I get this error: `GET http://titasos.com/Shop/high-tech/computer-and-console/computer.html net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` .

When I change `Use Web Server Rewrites` to `no` on `System>Configuration>Web>Search Engines Optimization`, error disappears, but after re-putting it to `yes` it come back.

Any solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just open `.htaccess` on the Magento root and comment the line `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]` like that: `##  RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`